# Auto-upload project

Tags: php, ftp, phpdesigner

Let's say I have a local project whose files are also stored online; now, with netbeans I would be able to give my local project FTP details so that it would upload the file whenever it's changed/saved.

How would I go about in doing that same thing in **PHPDesigner 8** (if possible, that is)?

Couldn't find much on Google, so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: i, myself, actually looking for this. couldn't find anything useful though.

Comment: Unfortunately I never found a solution to this, in the end I just switched back to Netbeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPDesigner 8 doesn't works differently to the Netbeans "Upload on Save".

I've set it up in the following way:

- Create a project (my repository is on my local drive).
- Add an FTP connection to the project.

Once you've done this, you can browse the remote FTP site.

- Double-clicking a file via FTP auto-downloads and opens it for editing in PHPDesigner.
- Saving changes auto-uploads the file back to the FTP site.
- You can then sync changes to your local drive using WinSCP (only need if your repository is local).